# Convexity of Root Quadratic Forms of Inverse P.D. Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Let $M$ be a positive definite matrix. Can one show that $\sqrt{x^\top M^{-1}x}$ is convex in M?

In other words, for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ positive definite, is the following true:
$$
(1-\lambda)\sqrt{x^\top (A)^{-1}x}+\lambda \sqrt{x^\top B^{-1}x} \geq \sqrt{x^\top ((1-\lambda)A+\lambda B)^{-1}x}
$$

It is known that without the square-root, $x^\top M^{-1}x$ is convex in M. This is by showing that the second derivative is positive in any direction, see e.g. [this short note](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31400997_A_Note_on_the_Expected_Value_of_an_Inverse_Matrix). I couldn't quite replicate the same approach on $\sqrt{x^\top M^{-1}x}$, since the additional square-root makes the second derivative expression much more complicated, and it does not easily reduce to a quadratic form.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is what I have tried. Denote $D = (1-\lambda)A+\lambda B$ and $C = B-A$. We will try to show that the following function is convex in $\lambda$ for any $x,A,B$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$:
$$
f(\lambda) = \sqrt{x^\top ((1-\lambda)A+\lambda B)^{-1}x}
$$

We do this by proving that $f''\geq 0$ for all $x,A,B$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

According to my calculations:
$$
f'' = -\frac{1}{4}\frac{(x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1} x)^2}{(x^\top D^{-1}x)^{1.5}} + \frac{x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1}CD^{-1} x}{(x^\top D^{-1}x)^{0.5}} 
$$

If the following is true:
$$
(x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1}CD^{-1} x)(x^\top D^{-1}x) \geq (x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1} x)^2
$$

This would imply that
$$
f'' \geq \frac{3}{4}\frac{(x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1} x)^2}{(x^\top D^{-1}x)^{1.5}}\geq 0
$$
since D is p.d.

Now, it is left to show $(x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1}CD^{-1} x)(x^\top D^{-1}x) \geq (x^\top D^{-1}CD^{-1} x)^2$. I've verified this with simulation and it seems to be correct, but I wasn't able to prove it.

Comment: Maybe try in the subspace of diagonal matrices first?

Comment: @copper.hat I've tried to simplify things in the case of diagonal matrices but it doesn't seem to help much in the way that I attempted to solve it. Edited the question to include my current attempt.